# Splitting a long word with space

Tags: sql-server-2008, split

I have a long string.I want to check throughout this string for consecutive 15 letters if there is no space i have to manually put a space in sql server. Can any one pls help??

```
For eg. my string is 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
then it should appear like 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP QRSTUVWXYZABCDE FGHIJKLMNOPQRST UVWXYZ'
```

Comment: You had to format part of your post as code in order for the system to let you ask this question. This is a strong hint you should post the code you have tried instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@dcp1986: I tried with your function as below.

```
SELECT dbo.UF_StringSplitter('HeloEveryonehru Howslyfgoingonn HaveaGoodDayGoodMorning')
```

But an unexpected split occured. I think your function must be modified as below for the correct result:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE ID = OBJECT_ID('UF_StringSplitter'))
    DROP FUNCTION UF_StringSplitter
GO

CREATE FUNCTION UF_StringSplitter (
 @psCSString VARCHAR(MAX)
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
 DECLARE @sTemp VARCHAR(MAX)
 DECLARE @tTemp VARCHAR(MAX)
 SET @tTemp=''

 WHILE LEN(@psCSString)>15
 BEGIN
  SET @sTemp = LEFT(LTRIM(@psCSString), 15)
  SET @psCSString = LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@psCSString,16, LEN(@psCSString)))

  IF @psCSString LIKE ' %'
     SET @tTemp=@tTemp+@sTemp   
  ELSE      
     SET @tTemp=@tTemp+@sTemp+' '      
 END
 SET @tTemp=@tTemp+@psCSString
RETURN @tTemp
END
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to do it on a single statement, but you can create a sql function something like this

```
create function AddStuffCharacterInLength (@original nvarchar(100), @take int, @stuff varchar(100))
returns nvarchar(200)
AS
BEGIN
    declare @result nvarchar(200)
declare @len int
declare @skip int

set @len = len(@original)
set @result = ''
set @skip = (@take * -1) + 1

    while @len > 0
    begin
        set @result = @result + substring(@original, @skip + @take, @take)
        set @len = @len - @take
        set @skip = @skip + @take
        if @len > 0
            set @result = @result + ' '
    end

    RETURN @result 
END
```

And use it like this

```
select dbo.AddStuffCharacterInLength ('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',15, ' ')
```

And the output should be

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO PQRSTUVWXYZABCD EFGHIJKLMNOPQRS TUVWXYZ

(1 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: try it again, it was an error with a variable being declared twice

Answer (score 1):

You could use a function like this

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE ID = OBJECT_ID('UF_StringSplitter'))
 DROP FUNCTION UF_StringSplitter
GO

CREATE FUNCTION UF_StringSplitter
(
 @psCSString VARCHAR(MAX)
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
 DECLARE @sTemp VARCHAR(MAX)
 DECLARE @tTemp VARCHAR(MAX)
 SET @tTemp=''

 WHILE LEN(@psCSString)>15
 BEGIN
  SET @sTemp = LEFT(@psCSString, 15)
  SET @psCSString = SUBSTRING(@psCSString,16, LEN(@psCSString))

  IF @psCSString LIKE ' %'
     SET @tTemp=@tTemp+@sTemp   
  ELSE      
     SET @tTemp=@tTemp+@sTemp+' '      
 END
 SET @tTemp=@tTemp+@psCSString
RETURN @tTemp
END
Go
```

Here i have hard coded the splitting value, and you can use the function

```
UPDATE mytable SET mycol=dbo.UF_StringSplitter(mycol)
```